# Is it possible to run vlc as root?

Tags: root, vlc

I installed VLC player using [this old video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Uql96eLe0w).

I don't know how to access other users, but root itself only, so I don't know if the video is outdated or works at all, anyway can I install VLC on root and run it from root as well?

Comment: First: what distribution are you using? Likely there is a vlc already packaged for it.

Comment: **BAD BAD BAD** -- Do not run as root.

Comment: If you actually did install vlc that way ... have you just tried running vlc as root? Why doesn't it work? What does happen when you try? What did you expect to go differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible — if you recompile VLC, passing `--enable-run-as-root` to `./configure`.

However, if you don't understand why it's dangerous to run VLC as root: **DON'T**.